# $ 4 + \sqrt{17} \approx \frac{2}{9} e^{(5/18) \pi \sqrt{17}}$ and other formulas

Tags: nt.number-theory, na.numerical-analysis

I found this formula attributed to [Kronecker](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=ASENS_1866_1_3__303_0) relating solutions of Pell equation to exponential sum:

$$ 4 + \sqrt{17} \approx \frac{2}{9} e^{(5/18) \pi \sqrt{17}} \text{ and } \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}e^{(1/10) \pi \sqrt{85}}$$

I can run this through a calculator and find both estimates quite convincing:

- $4 + \sqrt{17} = 8.12310\dots$
- $ \frac{2}{9} e^{(5/18) \pi \sqrt{17}}  =  8.117409\dots $
- $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}e^{(1/10) \pi \sqrt{85}} = 8.0985607\dots $

These are impressive but not out-of-this-world.  They are related to pell equation $t^2 - 17u^2 = - 1$ supposedly.  And we are supposed to estimate:
$$ \log \Big(t + u \sqrt{17}\Big)$$

in terms of theta functions.  Can any one supply the details here.  I know similar problems involving [$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer) that are related to the class number formula.

What is the name for the link to these approximations and Pell equation?

---

- [On $e^{\pi\sqrt{4\cdot163}}$ and unusual connections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192255/on-e-pi-sqrt4-cdot163-and-unusual-connections)
- [Why is $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{32}(29 + \sqrt{145}) \approx \pi$ ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67224/why-is-frac-sqrt63229-sqrt145-approx-pi)
- [Why are powers of $\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})$ almost integers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4775/why-are-powers-of-exp-pi-sqrt163-almost-integers?rq=1)

---

See also [History of the theory of numbers, Vol 2](https://archive.org/stream/historyoftheoryo02dickuoft#page/378/mode/2up)
(Eugene Dickson) p 378

Comment: These do not look remotely impressive to me! Can you give any more details? The exp(pi.sqrt(163)) story is to do with modular forms and imaginary quadratic fields; for real quadratic fields the story is different. The log of the fundamental solution to Pell's equation will show up in the formula of a special value of an L-function by the class number formula (so it's possible to imagine that $4+sqrt(17)$ is close to exp of something explicit) but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: The name is Kronecker's limit formula. Kronecker's solution of Pell's equation by means of special values of Dedekind's eta function was obtained by the limit formula (*Grenzformel*), and was regarded at the time as a crowning jewel of the theory of modular functions. You will enjoy reading about this in the last chapter of Andre Weil's book (*Elliptic functions according to Eisenstein and Kronecker*), or in Vladut's book on the Jugendtraum. The limit formula, giving close approximations of this type, was at the basis of the Gelfond-Linnik-Baker solution to Gauss's class number one problem.